# How to get hd_profile_pic_url_info from the instagram API using username?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have tried many solutions, but none of them working as of now. I have seen many apps are still able to find **hd_profile_pic_url_info**.

Could anyone please help me out, How these apps are showing the profile pic in HD?